# Store Multiple values MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working on the Learning Management System project.

Each student will have a class. In the classes table my phpMyAdmin want to store subjects of each class.

**Details:**

### tblStudents:

```
id |   Student Name | Class_id         
---------------------------------
 1 | student 1      |    1
 2 | student 2      |    2
```

### tblSubjects:

```
id |   Subject Name         
-------------------------
 1 |     Maths      
 2 |     Biology  
 3 |     Computer Science
```

### tblclasses:

```
id |        name         |  Subjects
-------------------------------------
 1 |      Diploma        |     *
 2 |      First Year     |     *
 3 |      2nd Year       |     *
```

*here I want to store all subjects of specific class but I don't know i which format I have to store subjects. just need some idea

Comment: You wouldn't. You would have a separate, normalised table for that

Comment: can anyone explain more, I'm not getting it? Thanks